# AWS Lambda + Angular web app throwing "Error: Cannot find module '@vendia/serverless-express'"

Tags: angular, amazon-web-services, serverless-framework, aws-serverless

I am trying to deploy angular web app on AWS serverless Lambda following the tutorial https://medium.com/better-programming/getting-started-with-serverless-angular-universal-on-aws-lambda-8754bcc4dc19

It was working fine till last week, but started to throw error "Error: Cannot find module '@vendia/serverless-express'" even though there is no mention of '@vendia/serverless-express' anywhere. The generated lambda.js uses'aws-serverless-express'.

Installed '@vendia/serverless-express' through npm, it got added to package.json. Deployed post that, still error is reported.

Steps to reproduce:

1. Ensure angular version is 7 or less as toolkit doesn't work with higher version
2. ng new project-name --style css --routing false
3. cd project-name
4. ng add @ng-toolkit/universal@7.1.2
5. npm run build:prod
6. npm run server
7. ng add @ng-toolkit/serverless@8.1.0
8. npm i serverless-api-compression
9. npm run build:serverless:deploy

Let me know in case of any further information required. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

aws-serverless-express has [rebranded to @vendia/serverless-express](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@vendia/serverless-express). The new path is not yet included in ng-toolkit's [serverless-aws.yml](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/schematics/serverless/src/files/aws/serverless-aws.yml#L16) file and that is what is causing the issue.

Adding the following in the [serverless.yml excludes](https://github.com/maciejtreder/ng-toolkit/blob/master/schematics/serverless/src/files/aws/serverless-aws.yml#L16) would solve the issue.

```
- '!node_modules/@vendia/**'
```

End result would be something like

```
package:
  exclude:
   - src/**
   - node_modules/**
   - firebug-lite/**
   - e2e/**
   - coverage/**
   - '!node_modules/@vendia/**'
   - '!node_modules/aws-serverless-express/**'
   - '!node_modules/binary-case/**'
   - '!node_modules/type-is/**'
   - '!node_modules/media-typer/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-types/**'
   - '!node_modules/mime-db/**'
```

Comment: Hi, do you know how to set it up now? since there has been more changes since then